# Customizing Minecraft overworld gen for half ores

Tags: json, minecraft

For my Minecraft server (java edition), I would like to halve the amount of all ores found in the overworld. The Minecraft official wiki says that the generation of the overworld and nether can be affected whilst everywhere else says you can only affect a custom dimension.

Is there any way to customize the normal overworld to have half the amount of ores in 1.16.4?

Answer (score 0):

In the world options for creating a world you can press more options and completely customize spawning of ores, etc.

Comment: I can't find these options. Default world customization was taken out of the world type menu a fair while ago if that what you're referring to. I can only affect whether there are structures, a bonus chest and if there is only one biome. I should have specified that I am on java edition if that is an issue, I will also specify this above.